# Update User Detail api returns DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, api, rest

I'm creating an update API that updates the profile of the super admin, I mapped the member table to a DTO, on the member table password is set to not null and I did not include the password field on the dto because there's a provision for that be, when I tested the API on postman it returned on the console

```
DataIntegrityViolationException
SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
Column 'password' cannot be null
```

Here is my code

Dto

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UpdateProfileDto {

    @NotNull(message = "{member.firstName.notNull}")
    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message = "{member.lastName.notNull}")
    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @JsonProperty("nationality")
    private Long nationality;

    @JsonProperty("country_of_residence")
    private Long countryOfResidence;

    @JsonProperty("date_of_birth")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @Past(message = "{customer.dateOfBirth.past}")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @JsonProperty("current_job_title")
    private String currentJobTitle;

    @NotNull(message = "{member.emailAddress.notNull}")
    @JsonProperty("email_address")
    private String emailAddress;

    @JsonProperty("username")
    private String username;

    @NotNull(message = "{member.phoneNumber.notNull}")
    @PhoneNumber
    @JsonProperty("phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Size(max = 300, message = "{member.city.size}")
    @JsonProperty("city")
    private String city;

    @Size(max = 300, message = "{member.state.size}")
    @JsonProperty("state")
    private String state;
}
```

ServiceImpl

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public Member updateProfile(UpdateProfileDto body) {
        Member superAdmin = repository.getOne(id);
        if (superAdmin == null) {
            throw new MemberNotFoundException(id);
        }

        Optional<Role> existingRole = roleJpaRepository.findByCode(RoleType.SUPER_ADMINISTRATOR.getValue());
        if (existingRole.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RoleNotFoundException(RoleType.SUPER_ADMINISTRATOR.getValue());
        }

        Member existing;

        existing = mapper.map(body, Member.class);
        existing.setPassword(superAdmin.getPassword());
        existing.getRoles().add(existingRole.get());
        existing.setNationality(countryRepository.getOne(body.getNationality()));
        existing.setCountryOfResidence(countryRepository.getOne(body.getCountryOfResidence()));
        return adminJpaRepository.save(existing);
    }
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(
        value = "super-admin",
        produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }
)
public class SuperAdminController {
    private final SuperAdminService service;
    public SuperAdminController(SuperAdminService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PutMapping("/update")
    public Member updateProfile(@Valid @RequestBody UpdateProfileDto body){
        Member superAdmin =  service.updateProfile(body);
        return superAdmin;
    }
}
```

The password bug has been fixed(changes reflected in serviceImpl), but when I run the code it returned `Duplicate entry 'ijava@gmail.com-111803918380' for key 'member.email_address_phone_number_uq'` email, and the phone number is set as a unique constraint in the member table, how can I bypass this?

Answer (score 1):

You have few options, depending on your exact use case.

1. Extract existing password, using unique property in `UpdateProfileDto`, email looks like it can do the job.

Pseudocode:

```
Member existing = repository.findByEmail;
Member superAdmin = mapper.map(body, Member.class);
superAdmin.setPassword(existing.getPassword());
```

2. Set a dummy value for password, to be updated later on.

```
superAdmin.setPassword("dummy-password");
```

3. Make the column nullable in database.

Comment: This helped fixed the password issue, however, now it displays `Duplicate entry 'java@gmail.com-111803918380' for key 'member.email_address_phone_number_uq' `

java@gmail.com is the existing email of the user I want to update, and in the member table or updateProfileDto email is not set to unique

Comment: The password bug has been fixed(changes reflected in serviceImpl), but when I run the code it returned `Duplicate entry 'ijava@gmail.com-111803918380' for key 'member.email_address_phone_number_uq'` email, and the phone number is set as a unique constraint in the member table, how can I bypass this?

Comment: @PlusUltra You are not supposed to bypass the constraint, but adhere to it. Judging by the name, this constraint sounds like a composite one, you can make a check in db, if a record exists, and if it does return an error response, same for the phone constraint.